# C# Trying to access the location of a panel's parent

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a main form with a tab control on it. The tabs get populated by adding panels from other forms within the solution. One of these panels has some code that will pop up an options window. I want that window to align itself to the top right hand side of the main form. To do this I need the location and size of the main form. However, I cannot seem to access any property that will tell one of the panels what the location of that main form is.

I've tried things like `this.Parent`, `this.ParentForm` and `this.GetContainerControl()`. They all return `null`.

Any ideas?

**Addendum**

```
//Code for the main form:
namespace WinAlignTest {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(new SomeApplication().panel1);
        }
    }
}



//Code that shows the option window
namespace WinAlignTest {
    public partial class SomeApplication : Form {
        private ApplicationOptions Options;
        public SomeApplication() {
            InitializeComponent();
            Options = new ApplicationOptions();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Options.Show();

            //This will always move the location to {0,0}
            Options.Location = new Point(base.Location.X,base.Location.Y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some sample code to show this part: "adding panels from other forms within the solution"?  It doesn't make sense that the parent is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused, you seem to be adding a panel which belongs to SomeApplication to Form1.  I would suggest you actually make SomeApplication a UserControl instead of a form:

```
//Code for the main form:
namespace WinAlignTest {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(new SomeApplication());
        }
    }
}

//Code that shows the option window
namespace WinAlignTest {
    public partial class SomeApplication : UserControl {
        private ApplicationOptions Options;
        public SomeApplication() {
            InitializeComponent();
            Options = new ApplicationOptions();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Options.Show();

            // You might need to use PointToScreen here
            Options.Location = this.Location;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you just exposed the real problem here. If I implement it as you suggest (as a UserControl) the .Parent functionality works as I would have expected.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the base identifier accesses a parent element.

Two possible problems: First, your constructors don't explicitly extend your base constructor. it would look like this:

```
public Form1():base(){}
```

I still recommend making getter methods in the Form1 class. It would look something like this:

```
public int Form1Location
{
   get{return /*FormLocation*/}
}
```

and call it from WinAlignTest

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Is there a way to upload a solution zip file?

Comment: How big are the files? All I need to see is the code for the main form and the pop-up window

Comment: got it, added it to the orriginal post

Comment: I tried extending Form1 and I couldn't get it to work. It might be possible, but I couldn't figure it out.  Anyway, the solution provided by ScottTx worked. Thanks for your help, though. I'm curious now if I can get your idea working. I'll have to play around with it when I get some time.

Answer (score 1):

Check out

```
Application.OpenForms
```

That should give you access to what you want.

Comment: This did the trick.  If you had multiple forms open, though, this could be a tricky solution to implement. Thanks for the help!